# Why is the main function not running in the REPL?

Tags: scala

This is a simple program. I expected `main` to run in interpreted mode. But the presence of another object caused it to do nothing. If the `QSort` were not present, the program would have executed.

Why is `main` not called when I run this in the REPL?

```
object MainObject{
  def main(args: Array[String])={
    val unsorted = List(8,3,1,0,4,6,4,6,5)
    print("hello" + unsorted toString)
    //val sorted = QSort(unsorted)
    //sorted foreach println
  }
}

//this must not be present

object QSort{
  def apply(array: List[Int]):List[Int]={
    array
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Sorry for causing confusion, I am running the script as `scala filename.scala`.

Comment: This snippet evaluates fine. What's your error message?

Comment: In both cases (with/without second object) main will not be evaluated.

Comment: Uh, it evaluates fine, but I expected `main` to actually execute

Comment: @aitchnyu, it will not. You should call `main` manually.

Comment: In case you're still wondering how to do that, type in `MainObject.main(null)`

Comment: @aitchnyu The behavior you're describing is not related to (pasting code in) the REPL (which you obtain by typing `scala` with no parameters) but by saving the script to a file and running `scala filename.scala`. Am I guessing right? In fact, as @om-nom-nom pointed out, in the REPL `main` methods are *never* executed (at least in 2.9, see his comment to my answer).

Comment: Yes, I am running `scala filename.scala`. I shouldnt have been calling it REPL, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### What's happening

If the parameter to `scala` is an existing .scala file, it will be compiled in-memory and run. **When there is a single top level object a main method will be searched and, if found, executed. If that's not the case the top level statements are wrapped in a synthetic main method which will get executed instead.**

This is why removing the top-level QSort objects allows your main method to run.

If you're going to expand this to a full program, I advise to compile and run (use a build tool like `sbt`) the compiled .class files:

```
scalac main.scala && scala MainObject
```

If you're writing a single file script, just drop the main method (and its object) and write the statements you want executed in the outer scope, like:

```
// qsort.scala
object QSort{
  def apply(array: List[Int]):List[Int]={
    array
  }
}

val unsorted = List(8,3,1,0,4,6,4,6,5)
print("hello" + unsorted toString)
val sorted = QSort(unsorted)
sorted foreach println
```

and run with: `scala qsort.scala`

#### A little context

The `scala` command is meant for executing both scala "scripts" (single file programs) and complex java-like programs (with a main object and a bunch of classes in the classpath).

From `man scala`:

```
   The  scala  utility  runs  Scala code using a Java runtime environment.
   The Scala code to run is specified in one of three ways:

      1.  With no arguments specified, a Scala shell starts and reads com-
          mands interactively.

      2.  With  -howtorun:object  specified, the fully qualified name of a
          top-level Scala object may be specified.  The object should pre-
          viously have been compiled using scalac(1).

      3.  With  -howtorun:script  specified,  a file containing Scala code
          may be specified.
```

If not explicitly specified, the `howtorun` mode is guessed from the arguments passed to the script.

When given a fully qualified name of an object, `scala` will guess `-howtorun:object` and expect a  compiled object with that name on the path.

Otherwise, if the parameter to `scala` is an existing .scala file, `-howtorun:script` is guessed and the entry point is selected as described above.

Comment: I'm a little tired, so forgive me for grammar errors / typos. Hope this helps.

Comment: *>the strange behaviour you get* I wouldn't say that this is a strange behavior.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I'm referring to the fact that by commenting out QSort the main method gets executed. This is kind of unexpected to me. Imagine I have a file with a single object + main method and I come back and add a single statement outside that object: that single-line change, possibily hidden at the end of the file, will completely change what's executed. I'd probably prefer main methods in top level objects in files to *never* be executed in `-howtorun:script` mode.

Comment: may be we have different versions of scala and that behavior changed, but in my REPL (2.9) [nothing is going to be executed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TfUt0.png)

Comment: @om-nom-nom and, you actually made me realize that it isn't the mode guessing to cause the main method to be executed when there's only one top level declaration (when a .scala file is found `-howtorun:script` is guessed anyway). Thanks for that.

Comment: @om-nom-nom yep, nothing is executed in my repl as well. I subconsciously guessed that the OP was referring to [executing a script *file*](http://cl.ly/1p1Y30383x3z2B030S05) with `scala filename.scala` and not to pasting into the repl.

Answer (score 11):

Any method of an object module can be run in REPL by explicitly specifying it and giving it the arguments it requires if any. For example:

```
scala> object MainObject{
     |   def main(args: Array[String])={
     |     val unsorted = List(9,3,1,0,7,5,9,3,11)
     |     print("sorted: " + unsorted.sorted)
     |   }
     |   def fun = println("fun here")
     | }
defined module MainObject

scala> MainObject.main(Array(""))
sorted: List(0, 1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 9, 11)
scala> MainObject.fun
fun here
```

In some cases this can be useful for quick testing and troubleshooting.