# Is there a reason why .scala file won't run/produce output on spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

I am trying to run an application that prints "Hello World!". The script works fine locally, but every time I run it with

```
:load /path/to/script
```

output:

```
    Loading /u/hdpdlcu/Matt/test/SparkScalaCourse/src/com/sundogsoftware/spark/test1.scala...
    defined object test1
```

I have tried starting it with spark-shell with

```
spark-shell -i /path/to/script
```

but that also fails to produce the output "Hello World"

I have tried calling .Main as well.

> scala> :load
>   /u/hdpdlcu/Matt/test/SparkScalaCourse/src/com/sundogsoftware/spark/test1.scala
>   Loading
>   /u/hdpdlcu/Matt/test/SparkScalaCourse/src/com/sundogsoftware/spark/test1.scala...
>   defined object test1
>
> scala>
>   /u/hdpdlcu/Matt/test/SparkScalaCourse/src/com/sundogsoftware/spark/test1.Main(Array("a"))
>   :1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
>   /u/hdpdlcu/Matt/test/SparkScalaCourse/src/com/sundogsoftware/spark/test1.Main(Array("a"))

I tried removing path to file after defining object test1:

```
scala> :load /u/hdpdlcu/Matt/test/SparkScalaCourse/src/com/sundogsoftware/spark/test1.scala
Loading /u/hdpdlcu/Matt/test/SparkScalaCourse/src/com/sundogsoftware/spark/test1.scala...
defined object test1

scala> test1.main("a")
<console>:26: error: value main is not a member of object test1
       test1.main("a")
             ^

scala> test1.main()
<console>:26: error: value main is not a member of object test1
       test1.main()
             ^
```

test1.scala:

```
package com.sundogsoftware.spark

object test1 {

  def Main (args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello World!")
  }
}
```

Comment: *defined object test1*. Seems like it loads the script correctly and without errors. Maybe try something like `test1.main()` and see if it works?

Comment: It is not working, because there it should be outputting "Hello World." I will update the OP to include contents of test1.scala

Comment: I have no issues running this code after pasting or `:load test1.scala` and then `test1.Main(Array("a"))`

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877314/why-is-the-main-function-not-running-in-the-repl

Comment: OP updated to add more information related to calling the main method.

Comment: You don't need the full path after the object is defined. Try : `scala > test1.Main("a"))`

Comment: calling test1.Main(Array("a")) without pathToScript after running the :load <pathToScript> worked.

Comment: If the linked question also solves your issue, please mark your question as duplicate so people are redirected to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

calling test1.Main(Array("a")) without pathToScript after running the :load  worked.